# play video immediately after recording on android app

Tags: android, video, mediarecorder

I am developing an app which should record a video of Maximum limit one minute, and saving it in gallery and then right after it saves it should start playing automatically. 
Following is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

private Camera myCamera;
  private MyCameraSurfaceView myCameraSurfaceView;
  private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;

Button myButton;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
boolean recording;

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      recording = false;

      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      //Get Camera for preview
      myCamera = getCameraInstance();
      if(myCamera == null){
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
         "Fail to get Camera",
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }

      myCameraSurfaceView = new MyCameraSurfaceView(this, myCamera);
      FrameLayout myCameraPreview = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.videoview);
      myCameraPreview.addView(myCameraSurfaceView);

      myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
      myButton.setOnClickListener(myButtonOnClickListener);
      Log.i("Camera !Error", "Cameray ka koi masla ni Agay chcek karo");
  }

  Button.OnClickListener myButtonOnClickListener
  = new Button.OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 if(recording){
              // stop recording and release camera
              mediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
              releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object

              //Exit after saved
              finish();
 }else{

  //Release Camera before MediaRecorder start
  releaseCamera();

        if(!prepareMediaRecorder()){
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
           "Fail in prepareMediaRecorder()!\n - Ended -",
           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         finish();
        }

  mediaRecorder.start();
  recording = true;
  myButton.setText("STOP");
  Log.i("Camera !Error", "Record to stop");
 }
}};

  private Camera getCameraInstance(){
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Camera c = null;
      try {
          c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
      }
      catch (Exception e){
          Log.i("Camera Error", "Camera Not Found");
      }
      Log.i("Camera Error", "Camera Found");
      return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}

private boolean prepareMediaRecorder(){
   myCamera = getCameraInstance();
   mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

   myCamera.unlock();
   mediaRecorder.setCamera(myCamera);

   mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
   mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

   mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

   mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/myvideo2.3gp");
      mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(10000); // Set max duration 10 sec.
      mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Set max file size 5M

   mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(myCameraSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());
   Log.i("Camera Error", "Media Recorder is ready");

   try {
       mediaRecorder.prepare();
   } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
       releaseMediaRecorder();
       return false;
   } catch (IOException e) {
       releaseMediaRecorder();
       return false;
   }
   return true;

}

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      releaseMediaRecorder();       // if you are using MediaRecorder, release it first
      releaseCamera();              // release the camera immediately on pause event
  }

  private void releaseMediaRecorder(){
      if (mediaRecorder != null) {
          mediaRecorder.reset();   // clear recorder configuration
          mediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
          mediaRecorder = null;
          myCamera.lock();           // lock camera for later use
      }
      Log.i("Media Recorder", "Media Recorer Released");

  }

  private void releaseCamera(){
      if (myCamera != null){
          myCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
          myCamera = null;
      }
      Log.i("Camera Recorder", "Camera Released");
  }

public class MyCameraSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
   private Camera mCamera;

public MyCameraSurfaceView(Context context, Camera camera) {
       super(context);
       mCamera = camera;

       // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
       // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
       mHolder = getHolder();
       mHolder.addCallback(this);
       // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
       mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
   }

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int weight,
  int height) {
       // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
       // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

       if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
         // preview surface does not exist
         return;
       }

       // stop preview before making changes
       try {
           mCamera.stopPreview();
       } catch (Exception e){
         // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
       }

       // make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here

       // start preview with new settings
       try {
           mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
           mCamera.startPreview();

       } catch (Exception e){
       }
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
       try {
           mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
           mCamera.startPreview();
       } catch (IOException e) {
       }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
}
```

my main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/videoview"
android:layout_width="720px"
android:layout_height="480px"/>
<Button
android:id="@+id/mybutton"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="REC"
android:textSize="12sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

On button click recording starts and on click again, it stops and exits using 
finish() for this purpose. Here i want that instead of exiting the recorded video should start.
Hope i managed to clearly explain my question.

Comment: do you wan to play the video using the media player apps? or using videoview in your apps?

Comment: I want to use VideoView

Comment: then what is the problem>? you can simply add videoview in the xml and where you are calling finish() there you can start the video in video view? exactly at which point you are facing problem?

Comment: how can i start the video in the video view. Like what function to call and how to give path of the latest saved video.

Comment: why don't you just go to this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html and see videoview api references.. You can just call setvideopath then start